# fetch data other url with call ajax(cross domain)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at  This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Comment: $.ajax({
   url : 'http://117.218.165.145:7172/Schooly1000/rest/newsservice/news',
      success:function() {
                alert("Success");
            },
            error:function() {
                alert("Error");
            },
            dataType:"jsonp",
            type:"get"
     });

Comment: Do you have access for both client and sever applications? And which browser are you using to perform above request?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access content on remote servers if they do not have the CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing) headers enabled. If you are running the server you should turn it on on your server application, if not you might want to look into proxying the data through a server on which you can turn on cors.